# Dell Laptop does not find integrated Webcam

Tags: dell, webcam, 23.04

I have a Dell Latitude 7640. I am running on this Laptop Ubuntu 23.04 and Windows 11. So the problem is, that Windows does find my integrated camera, but when I open cheese in Ubuntu, then it does say "No device found". I also tried to find my camera in terminal with couple of commands but nothing seems to recognize a webcam. What can I do?

Edit:
I can not see any camera devices, when I run `sudo journalctl  -b  0`

After typing this command `sudo lshw -C video` I get this output:

```
  *-display                 
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Version: 04
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       Ressourcen: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:201 memory:6055000000-6055ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

With this command `ls -l /dev/vid*;id` I get:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Mai 30 10:07 /dev/video0
uid=1000(nathan) gid=1000(nathan) Gruppen=1000(nathan),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),100(users),118(lpadmin)
```

Comment: Does your system see the camera at startup? The terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b  0` will let you page through the logs. Also, `sudo lshw -C video`. Is it a permission/group issue? `ls -l /dev/vid*;id`. Please [edit] your post to  new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers).  Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question. Help us help you.

Comment: I edited my post now, hope this helps

Comment: Have you tried plugging in a webcam to see if it shows up with Cheese?

Comment: BTW `sudo lshw -C Video` will not show the camera. Just run `sudo lshw` and look for the camera in the results, or you can use `sudo lshw | grep Webcam`

Answer (score 0):

The command and its result:

```
ls -l /dev/vid*;id
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Mai 30 10:07 /dev/video0
uid=1000(nathan) gid=1000(nathan) Gruppen=1000(nathan),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),100(users),118(lpadmin)
```

show us that:

1. You're producing non-English outputs. Since AskUbuntu is an English language site, you should preface your commands with `LANG=C command` to generate messages in English.
2. `/dev/video0` is owned by `[root,video]`.
3. `/dev/video0`'s permissions (`rw-rw----`) say it can be read/written by its owner (`root`) and by members of the `video` group, and NOT by "other".
4. The `id` command shows that you're not in the `video` group, so you're "other".

To fix, join the `video` group:

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Then logout/login, because groups are set up by `login`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you wrote, but it still does not work. I don't know if it is relevant too, but I am using this IPU6, which I read that I should install (but still not working).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device & system and I am facing the same problem.

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

produces

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:201 memory:6055000000-6055ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

And

```
ls -l /dev/vid*;id
```

returns

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/vid*': No such file or directory
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),135(lxd),136(sambashare)
```

When plugging in an external webcam and asking `lsusb` I get

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0c45:6367 Microdia USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please see my comments above to the OP.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to an external webcam right now, but will try this soon. Adding myself to the video group did not help. `sudo lshw | grep Webcam` initiated a brief search but did not produce any output.

Comment: The next step will be to try an external plug-in webcam and see if your laptop recognizes it.

Comment: The external plug-in webcam is recognized. But not the integrated one.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb` to your "answer" with the external webcam plugged in.

Comment: Sure, done now.

Comment: Can you ask a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and put the link here so I can see it? There are a lot of things to troubleshoot and it is better if you ask your own question since the OP is no longer participating. You can copy and paste the above into your question. Also mention if your built in webcam works with Windows

Comment: Done. Here is the new question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1472443/integrated-webcam-not-working-on-dell-latitude-7640-running-ubuntu-23-04