# Integrated camera not working on Dell Latitude 7440 and 7340. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dell, intel-graphics, webcam

For context I have the same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469929/dell-laptop-does-not-find-integrated-webcam) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1472443/integrated-webcam-not-working-on-dell-latitude-7640-running-ubuntu-23-04), but lack the reputation to comment on those. So since I do not have the answer, but have managed to get closer to an answer I ask here so we may be able to bring this problem forward. I use Ubuntu 22.04 but the problems are the same.

lshw find the camera as multimedia, not video.

```
sudo lshw -C multimedia
```

Before any drivers has been installed I get

```
 *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED  
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6052000000-6052ffffff
```

After I have installed the driver as explained below I get

```
  *-multimedia:0            
   description: Multimedia controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 5
   bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=intel-ipu6 latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff
```

To get this far I have installed the [IPU6/IPU6EP stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell) manually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-ivsc-generic-hwe-22.04
sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
sudo reboot
```

Now we have /dev/video

```
ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 juni  19 14:24 /dev/video0
crw-rw----  1 root video 81, 1 juni  19 14:24 /dev/video1
```

Add video group to your user any way you like (I use pam_group and /etc/security/groups.conf)

Zoom is now able to recognize the camera as an "Intel MIPI Camera", but still refuses to show me video.

I get kernel errors

```
dmesg |grep ipu6
[    4.449996] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.450272] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Device 0xa75d (rev: 0x1)
[    4.450295] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: physical base address 0x6052000000
[    4.450298] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: mapped as: 0x00000000ba3d362f
[    4.450354] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU in secure mode
[    4.450355] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.450357] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU camera mask = 0x0
[    4.466705] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPC reset done
[    4.466710] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.468556] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: FW version: 20220510
[    4.473948] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Found supported sensor INT3537:00
[    4.474049] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Connected 1 cameras
[    4.475954] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
[    4.488770] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
[    4.566919] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: CSE authenticate_run done
[    4.566963] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU6-v3 driver version 1.0
[    4.622336] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: pkg_dir entry count:8
[    4.622623] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: psys probe minor: 0
[   11.923791] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: isys port open ready failed -16
[   11.923799] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Device close failure: -16
[   13.925869] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Device release time out -16
[   13.925882] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Clearing old context
[   13.925906] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: isys fw com open failed -5
[   14.034750] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: bind hi556 15-0020 nlanes is 2 port is 1
[   14.034798] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: All sensor registration completed.
[   19.236907] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Clearing old context
[   19.236927] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: isys fw com open failed -5
```

The first time I tried installing the Intel-drivers from the oem-solutions-group PPA everything worked. I got video in Zoom and even Cheese worked as it should. I have however not been able to replicate this result after I reinstalled to make sure I could describe the process for future installations.

Answer (score 4):

We also used what user112594 (thumbs up, big thank you) posted and:

**Step 1**
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6` 
`sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-ivsc-generic-hwe-22.04`
`sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0`

**Step 2**
`shutdown now`

**Step 3**
`sudo lshw -C multimedia`
*#multimedia:0 should appear without UNCLAIMED after it.*

**Step 4**
*#add user to group video (might need restart/reboot so that group video appear in groups)*
`sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`
**Step 5**
*#comment with # the line containing v4l2 in file media-session.conf found in /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d so:*
`cd /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d`
`sudo nano media-session.conf`
*#comment that line starting with v4l2*
*#ctrl+o enter (save over the existing file) then ctrl+x to close nano.*
`shutdown now`

Now camera should work (at least for google meets) in CHROME browser...

Comment: Confirmed working for dell latitude 7440

Comment: @gork mate you have saved people's life. Working on Latitude 7440.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by [this workaround](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta
sudo apt install oem-somerville-tentacool-meta
sudo apt update
```

And restart :)