Webcam not working on Kubuntu 24.04 on a DELL 5480
this is a known issue with *ubuntu and Dell laptops, there are hundreds of hits to this question; the webcam is simply not recognized by the system and one needs to add a ppa repo (this one: ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta) and stuff is sort of solved (alternatively, the solution is simlar and asks to add libcamhal).
I solved the problem before on my Dell, that way.
But: now that I updated to 24.04 it is of course no more, since that ppa repo does not work with 24.04.
Solutions?
I thought of

forcing Kubuntu to accept the old (22.04) version of that repo. But I fail. Any hint on how to do this?
waiting for the 24.04 repo to be available... but that might be a long wait and I need my webcam now.

Thanks!
I add here some diagnostics as asked in the comments (thanks).
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

Also, the webcam is now seen by the system (I added the ipu6 module to the kernel and libcamhal):
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
        /dev/video0


But the camera seems to be UNCLAIMED
sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED  
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:628e000000-628effffff




Please run lsb_release -a

Upgrades to 24.04 are not enabled, there is your mistake.

I understand @mikewhatever, but it's not as if I'm jumping off a cliff, 24.04 is an LTS release

@petep here it is
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

Well, I hope the PPA gets updated sooner rather than later. Bad decisions have consequences, not sure what it has to do with "jumping off a cliff". ...by the way, how do you know which package to install?

No offense meant -- I just thought that upgrading to an LTS, with standard hardware shipped on basically half of Dell products and for which all had been solved earlier wouldn't be a bad decision. Turns out I was wrong :-)
As for the packages, I followed this question (and others to the same tune) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473289/integrated-camera-not-working-on-dell-latitude-7440-and-7340-ubuntu-22-04?rq=1

v4l2-ctl --list-devices

@petep thanks. Edited the main question to add the elements.
ALso here: v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video0

what app did you try that dont work?

@petep: none works. the camera does not turn on. Cheese won't work, kamoso won't work, zoom, meet, none. It is as if it wasn't there.

try vlc or gstreamer. I would recomend.

It must be frustrating that Dell's "standard hardware" needs a PPA to work, but given the arrangement, there is likely not much anyone here can do. Also, complaining here is probably as useless as complaining gets. Perhaps you can contact Dell, and make your displeasure known where it matters.

@mikewathever of course it's frustrating but I was not complaining in the original post, just asking if someone has had the same problem yet (many will, as they upgrade to 24.04) and if there were solutions. Of course I'll let it be known at Dell. And as soon as I have an answer I'l post it her,e it could help some lost soul down along the way

https://launchpad.net/~oem-solutions-group/+archive/ubuntu/intel-ipu6?field.series_filter=noble is available. If you follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelMIPICamera, you should be able to make it work. Test with https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html or your own workflow.

Update: Dell officially replied to me in the Dell forums telling me that the MIPI driver is not available for Ubuntu 24.04, and that's it, no webcam.
Cit from the source:
Precision 5480 webcam does not work on Ubuntu 24.04. If other systems use the same camera, then they also will not function on Ubuntu 24.04. Ubuntu 24.04 does not support the MIPI (Mobile Industry Processor Interface) webcam.
Ubuntu 24.04 is not present on any of these system Drivers & Download pages. Dell only tested the operating systems shown on those specific Drivers & Downloads pages.

Reddit thread discussing same issue

The problem has been solved as of July 11th, 2024: Ubuntu posted an updated Kernel that fixed the problem for the 24.04 issue.
In particular, the update involved the packages
linux-modules-6.8.0-1007-oem:amd64 (6.8.0-1007.7, automatic),
linux-modules-ipu6-oem-24.04a:amd64 (6.8.0-1007.7),
linux-modules-ipu6-6.8.0-1007-oem:amd64 (6.8.0-1007.7, automatic), linux-image-6.8.0-1007-oem:amd64 (6.8.0-1007.7, automatic)

A complete answer would be what kernel fixed it for you. Please add this info to the answer.

@david done as requested, thanks

Doing uname -r, I see I'm still on 6.8.0-41-generic.  Do I need to move to an OEM kernel, or if I just wait and get the auto updates, will I eventually get the fix in the generic kernel?

The answer here worked for me on Dell Precision 5690.
As in that answer, I did:
sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic
sudo apt install ubuntu-oem-keyring # necessary for the following repository
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ noble somerville
sudo apt install libcamhal0

then restarted my machine and the webcam works now.  Although the video quality is pretty bad (when you move its very laggy and leaves a trail and has what looks like heavy compression effects).  Looking at reviews like this one, it should be quite good quality.

interesting, but nothing here that i could just copy and paste (or in the intel github) helped me in my dell 7230. :( if anything, i just managed to get different errors and did not bother to understand them properly. the wiki at ubuntu has more "useless" info that makes me feel like there is no solution for my case yet! crazy to think the main issue has been found months ago, and perhaps it just doesn't work for me because i kept ubuntu updated. argh. thanks for sharing anyway, garrett!
